# how to open multiple files in vim after vimgrep

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I'm using gvim.  Using `vimgrep` on current directory to find text across `*.sql` files. As it searches files, it just shows me file name at a time and in the end opens one file up.

Is it possible to open all files as tabs? Basically I want to open all files because I want to replace the 'vimgrepped' pattern with a some other text.

Comment: This is a little hard, because the quickfix list stores locations, not just files.

Comment: so should I just search and replace on multiple files? and forget about opening them..

Comment: I still need a list of file names that got affected..

Comment: You could use `:cw` to open the list in a window, then extract the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate actions on the QuickFix list locations, I have written a command
similar to `:bufdo` or `:windo` that executes a command for each item.

```
command! -nargs=+ Qfixdo call QuickFixDo(<q-args>)
function! QuickFixDo(cmd)
    let bufnam = {}
    for q in getqflist()
        let bufnam[q.bufnr] = bufname(q.bufnr)
    endfor  
    for n in keys(bufnam)
        exe 'buffer' n
        exe a:cmd
        update
    endfor
endfunction
```

Using the function one can open all files mentioned in the QuickFix list by
the following command.

```
:Qfixdo tab sp
```

In addition, it is possible to repeat the substitution itself the same way.

```
:Qfixdo %s/pattern/string/
```

Comment: I like this solution, but please [give credit where due](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316).

Comment: @nelstrom: Wow!  It is interesting to see how thinking the Vim way could produce almost identical solutions to similar problems.  Nevertheless, I came up with this function myself, so the credit for this particular answer is not due to Al, even though the code is indeed very similar.

Comment: @ib my apologies. It seems daft that Vim doesn't have some kind of *quickfixdo* built in, considering that it has `bufdo`, `windo`, `tabdo` and `argdo`.

Comment: @nelstrom:  Don't mention it.  Totally agree about the absence of a built-in command for repeating a command on the QuickFix list files.  In fact, that is exactly the reason why Vim users would reinvent it over and over.

Comment: @nelstrom: By the way, searching similar solutions on Stack Overflow (after reading your comment), I found [your idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686206/search-replace-using-quickfix-list-in-vim/5686810#5686810) of setting `args` to the QuickFix list files and using `argdo`.  That's a very elegant workaround!

Answer (score 1):

found this plugin pretty helpful in this regard.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813