# How to do search & replace with ack in vim?

Tags: search, vim, replace, ack

I am using the Ack plugin in Vim, which helps me to quickly search for strings in my project. However, sometimes I want to replace all or some occurrences of the found strings. You can do some kind of global search and replace using the Vim arglist like this ([source](http://www.ibrahim-ahmed.com/2008/01/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in.html))
:

```
:args app/views/*/*
:argdo %s/, :expire.*)/)/ge | update
```

But instead of using `args`, I would prefer to do a search via Ack and then do the replace in all files that have been found. Is there a way to do it similar to the `argdo` command?

Answer (score 98):

I've decided to use `ack` and `perl` to solve this problem outside of Vim so I could use the more powerful Perl regular expressions instead of the GNU subset.  You could map this to a key stroke in your `.vimrc`.

```sh
ack -l 'pattern' | xargs perl -pi -E 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

## Explanation

### `ack`

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) is an awesome command line tool that is a mix of `grep`, `find`, and full Perl regular expressions (not just the GNU subset).  It's written in pure Perl, it's fast, it has match highlighting, it works on Windows and it's friendlier to programmers than the traditional command line tools.  Install it on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install ack-grep`.

### `xargs`

[xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) is an old Unix command line tool.  It reads items from standard input and executes the command specified followed by the items read for standard input.  So basically the list of files generated by `ack` are being appended to the end of the `perl -pi -E 's/pattern/replacement/g'` command.

### `perl -pi -E`

Perl is a programming language.

The `-p` option causes Perl to create a loop around your program which iterates over filename arguments.

The `-i` option causes Perl to edit the file in place. You can modify this to create backups.

The `-E` option causes Perl to execute the one line of code specified as the program. In our case the program is just a Perl regex substitution.

For more information on Perl command line options, see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  For more information on Perl, see http://www.perl.org/.

Comment: +1 I slightly my solution to use sed since perl wasn't installed: 
ack -l OLD_TEXT | xargs sed -i "" "s/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/g

Comment: @Eric Johnson, why did you use `-E` switch for `perl` here ? I see no use of any _feature_

Comment: @sputnick, I just always use -E out of habit so I have 'say' available.  -e works just as well of course.

Comment: This throws errors for me unless I tell ack to list just the files with `-l` like this: `ack -l 'pattern' | xargs perl -pi -E 's/pattern/replacement/g'`

Comment: @tommychheng How do you run ack without perl?

Comment: This should added on the Documentation section. What nice line of script.

Comment: is it somehow possible to ask for confirmation for every change?

Answer (score 53):

Now, Vim has this new command `cdo` that will run the given command to each line of the quickfix list.

So you can use

```
:Ack pattern
:cdo s/pattern/newpattern/g
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Since vim 7.4, this is the right answer.  One slight tweak, for the OP, :cfdo might be more appropriate.

Comment: i may be missing something obvious, but I'm running Vim 7.4 on fedora and I get `not and editor command` whenever I try `:cdo`, any ideas?

Comment: From the help page, you need your vim compiled with the `+listcmds` feature. Does it explain the missing command?

Comment: `:cdo s/pattern/newpattern/g | update` worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I don't believe there's a built in way of doing this, but it should be easy to make one.

What you need to do is create a command that calls a custom function.  The function should then use the `getqflist()` function to get all of the entries in the quickfix list and `exe` to do the dirty work.  Be careful what you pass as an argument!

```
" Define a command to make it easier to use
command! -nargs=+ QFDo call QFDo(<q-args>)

" Function that does the work
function! QFDo(command)
    " Create a dictionary so that we can
    " get the list of buffers rather than the
    " list of lines in buffers (easy way
    " to get unique entries)
    let buffer_numbers = {}
    " For each entry, use the buffer number as 
    " a dictionary key (won't get repeats)
    for fixlist_entry in getqflist()
        let buffer_numbers[fixlist_entry['bufnr']] = 1
    endfor
    " Make it into a list as it seems cleaner
    let buffer_number_list = keys(buffer_numbers)

    " For each buffer
    for num in buffer_number_list
        " Select the buffer
        exe 'buffer' num
        " Run the command that's passed as an argument
        exe a:command
        " Save if necessary
        update
    endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Suppose you do something like `:QFDo v/skipPat/s/Pat/Rep/gce`
and there is a large list of buffers on quickfix window. Then on the first
file you notice you mistyped the replacement string Rep. Typing `Ctrl-c`
won't stop the command, but only the replace command on current line - it
will require a `Ctrl-c` for every line matched on each buffer. Is there any
trick to catch the `Ctrl-c` or `ESC` key and break the `for` statement on function
above?

Comment: See also [this article](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) based on the answer above, which gave origin to [this plugin](https://github.com/henrik/vim-qargs).

Answer (score 10):

You could using ack by this way

```
:args `ack -l User app/`
:argdo %s/, :expire.*)/)/ge | update
```

Or use ag

```
:args `ag -l User app/`
:argdo %s/, :expire.*)/)/gec | w
```

Answer (score 9):

I use MacVim (activated with `mvim` in a shell). I pipe the results of `ack` to `mvim`:

```
mvim -f $(ack -l $@)
```

Then in MacVim, I search/replace using `bufdo`:

```
:bufdo %s/SEARCH/REPLACE/gce | update
```

Omit the `c` option if confirmation is not needed.

Comment: do vim -p $(ack -Qil "string to match") to get these to launch in individual tabs (if that's your thing!)