# Capturing break/interrupt command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to interrupt a `for` loop such as in code below,

```
for num in buffer_number_list
    " Select the buffer
    exe 'buffer' num
    " Run the command that's passed as an argument
    exe a:command
    " Save if necessary
    update
endfor
```

instead of interrupting only line `exe a:command`, when `a:command` is a
`:s/// command`.

The purpose is to change code on response to [How to do search & replace with ack in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316)

I've tried surrounding the line `exe a:command` with a `try`/`catch` block,
but it doesn't worked, probably because the command handled the interrupt
signal without re-throwing it.

Tried remapping `CTRL-c` to change some variable (which would be checked inside of the loop), but it didn't worked:

```
let original_Ctrl_c = maparg('<c-c>', 'n')
exe 'nnoremap <c-c> :call <SID>BreakLoop()<CR>' . original_Ctrl_c
```

It seems that the mapping didn't trigger when the interrupt signal is
caught.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

It seems that this problem only occurs in gVim (thanks @ib.)

Comment: using your `QFDo` function would this be closer to the effect you are looking for: `function! QFDo(command) abort`?

Comment: @PeterRincker The idea is similar to that, but I've tested and it doesn't worked. Maybe it is because the `CTRL-c` is intercepted by the command.

Comment: how about `v:errmsg`. see `:h v:errmsg`.

Comment: @PeterRincker how exactly you sugest to use this variable? I've performed some tests and typing Ctrl-c to interrupt a :s/// command doesn't changed it at all.

Comment: I have my own copy of `QFDo` (basically the same except no `update`) and I do not see the behavior you are trying to avoid. Maybe I am missing something, but I would imagine between using `try`/`finally`, `abort`, and `v:errmsg` do not work then it may be un-catch-able. The only thing left I can think of is setting some global variable like you are using. Make sure you use `g:variable_name`

Comment: Could you provide the exact code of your function as well as the command you are passing into it to run?  If I understand the question correctly, pressing `Ctrl`+`C` when that function is running a particular command does not interrupt the loop over buffers and does not terminate the function?

Comment: @ib. Yes, you understood the question correctly. The exact code of the function and the command passed to it is on the link referenced on the question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316 (command `v/skipPat/s/Pat/Rep/gce`). Let me know if you think it is better to copy that code to this question.

Comment: @mMontu:  Trying to reproduce the behavior you describe I have created two identical files, `$ echo -e "skip\npat\npat" | tee a1 >a2`, and opened Vim with all initializations disabled, `$ vim -u NONE`.  Then I have sourced the file containing only the code of that `QFDo` function, `:so qfdo.vim`, and run `:vimgrep /skip/ a?`.  Interrupting the command `:QFDo v/skip/s/pat/rep/gce` with `Ctrl`+`C` after the first replacement (in `a1` file), *terminates the whole `:QFDo` command* (`a2` remains untouched).  Could you reproduce these steps and confirm that in your case `:QFDo` does not terminate?

Comment: @ib. I've reproduced the steps you described and the problem didn't show up indeed. But it does shows up when I replace `$ vim -u NONE` with `$ vim -gu NONE` (gVim instead of console vim).

Comment: @mMontu:  This fact means that the behavior you are trying to overcome is caused by some `.vimrc` configuration or plugin.  Try to enabling them one by one and repeating the test I propose to detect the plugin that breaks `Ctrl`+`C` termination.

Comment: @mMontu:  Regarding GVim, I bet that if you run it with `$ vim -g -u NONE -U NONE` the problem will not occur either.  By the way, should I add the "testing" procedure as an answer?

Comment: @ib. You are right, the problem didn't showed up in gVim either with the command you proposed. I've investigated the .vimrc/plugins as you sugested, and the culprit seems to be line `vnoremap <C-C> "+y`in  `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`. Thank you very much! Please add your comments as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to reproduce the behavior you describe I have constructed the following
test case.  It includes two identical files created using the command

```
$ echo -e "skip\npat\npat" | tee tmp1 >tmp2
```

and opened in Vim without any initialization apart from sourcing the file
containing implementation of the `:QFDo` command:

```
$ vim -u NONE -S qfdo.vim
```

or

```
$ gvim -u NONE -U NONE -S qfdo.vim
```

Searching for a pattern in those two files,

```
:vimgrep /pat/ tmp{1,2}
```

populates the contents of the quickfix window that can be used to run the
command in question,

```
:QFDo v/skip/s/pat/rep/gce
```

Interrupting this command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after the first
replacement, which occurs to be in the file `tmp1`, terminates the whole
`:QFDo` command, and therefore the file `tmp2` remains untouched.  This fact
means that the behavior you are trying to overcome is caused by some `.vimrc`
customization or plugin.  To locate the actual configuration breaking
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> behavior, disable all of the plugins and try
enabling them one by one running the above test case each time.

Comment: @ib.I was trying to avoid the problem in `QFDo` function by unmapping the `Ctrl-c` before entering the for loop, then restoring it in a finally block, but didn't work. After some investigation I'm suspicious that it is a vim bug. To reproduce: `$ echo "for i in range(1,4) | %s/r/x/gc | endfor" > temp.vim` and `$ vim -N -u NONE -U NONE temp.vim`.  Then `:so %` and `Ctrl-c` interrupted the loop.  But after entering `:map <c-c> abc` and `:unmap <c-c>` the `:so %` is NOT interrupted by `Ctrl-c` anymore. If you can confirm that it also happens on your machine I will report this as a bug

Comment: @mMontu:  Yes, mapping and un-mapping of `Ctrl`+`C` makes it behave as `Esc` in `:substitute` prompts--in your example it is necessary to press `Ctrl`+`C` four times in a row to stop substitutions.  However, while it is certainly strange, I am not completely sure this is a bug after reading `:h map_CTRL-C`.