# Search & replace using quickfix list in Vim

Tags: search, vim, replace

So far I always used EasyGrep for replacing text in multiple files. Unfortunately it is quite slow when a project gets bigger. One thing that seems to be amazingly fast is Ggrep of fugitive.vim that only search my version controlled files. All results are also stored in the quickfix list.

How can I use the results of Ggrep for doing a simple replace over all those found files? Is it somehow possible to use `%s/foo/bar/cg` on all files in the quickfix list or are there any better ways?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Update:**
Vim now has `cdo`, see [Sid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559267/23566).

**Original Answer:**

Vim has [`bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bufdo), [`windo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:windo), [`tabdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabdo) and [`argdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:argdo), which let you perform the same command in all open buffers, windows or files in the argument list. What we really need is something like `quickfixdo`, which would invoke a command on every file in the quickfix list. Sadly, that functionality is lacking from Vim, but [here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316) by [Al](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72791/al) that provides a home-rolled solution. Using this, it would be possible to run:

```
:QFDo %s/foo/bar/gc
```

And that would run the foo/bar substitution on all files in the quickfix list.

The `bufdo`, `windo`, `tabdo` and `argdo` commands have some common behaviour. For example, if the current file can't be abandoned, then all of these commands will fail. I'm not sure if the `QFDo` command referenced above follows the same conventions.

I've adapted [Al's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316) to create a command called `Qargs`. Running this command populates the argument list with all of the files listed in the quickfix list:

```
command! -nargs=0 -bar Qargs execute 'args ' . QuickfixFilenames()
function! QuickfixFilenames()
  " Building a hash ensures we get each buffer only once
  let buffer_numbers = {}
  for quickfix_item in getqflist()
    let buffer_numbers[quickfix_item['bufnr']] = bufname(quickfix_item['bufnr'])
  endfor
  return join(values(buffer_numbers))
endfunction
```

Using this, you could follow these steps to do a project-wide search and replace:

```
:Ggrep findme
:Qargs
:argdo %s/findme/replacement/gc
:argdo update
```

**Edit: *(with a hat tip to Peter Rincker)***

Or you could join the last 3 commands together in a single line:

```
:Ggrep findme
:Qargs | argdo %s/findme/replacement/gc | update
```

Comment: I believe you should be using `-nargs=0` and `-bar` in your `Qargs` command.

Comment: It's an elegant idea to use `args` and `argdo`!  I think it could be even better (and more convenient) to join `Qargs` and `argdo` commands in one: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=command -bang Qargdo exe 'args '.QuickfixFilenames() | argdo<bang> <args>`

Comment: I've created a simple plugin to wrap the `:Qargs` command: https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-qargs

Comment: @ib. Thanks for that (and to @nelstrom, of course). Forked @nelstrom's plugin to add your `Qargdo`, but as `Qdo` for less command completion conflicts: https://github.com/henrik/vim-qargs

Comment: A patch [was submitted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/dfyt-G6SMec/_6h8pDUpeZMJ) to add the :cdo and :ldo commands to Vim.

Comment: Should note in the answer that :`hidden` needs to be on (perhaps as a note to beginners, at the end).

Answer (score 67):

`cdo` command has now been added! After you grep, you can use `cdo` to execute the given command to each term in your quickfix list:

`cdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/cg`

(Take a look at this [git commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/aa23b379421aa214e6543b06c974594a25799b09) and this [vim developers google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_dev/cdo/vim_dev/dfyt-G6SMec/_6h8pDUpeZMJ) for more information on `cdo` and the motivations behind adding it.)

Comment: I think replace command should not include `%` to prevent replacement in lines outside of selected list. Also it may cause unexpected result if replace isn't idempotent.

Comment: Using `cdo` also opens up the amazing slew of options available to more flexible operations. Eg `cdo norm capMy new paragraph` This example runs `normal` at every occurrence of the search term, changing the entire paragraph around the search term to read "My new paragraph". Amazingly powerful.

Comment: I also needed to pipe the above to "update" command, otherwise vim didn't want to move to next file because the buffer was edited but not saved. Command `:cdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/gc | update`

Answer (score 16):

nelstrom's answer is quite comprehensive and reflects his brilliant contributions to vimdom. It also goes a bit beyond what is strictly needed here; the quickfix step can be omitted in favor of populating args with the result of a shell command:

```
:args `git grep -l findme`
:argdo %s/findme/replacement/gc
:argdo update
```

should be all you need.

Edit: as Domon notes, :set hidden must be done first if it's not already set!

Comment: +1 for pragmatic solution. Based on this you could also populate the arglist when you start vim: `vim \`git grep -l findme\``

Comment: This works for me. However, I have to `:set hidden` before `:argo ...` or Vim gives errors because of unsaved changes.

Answer (score 5):

Using [quickfix-reflector.vim](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim), you can edit your search results in the quickfix window. The `write` command will then save the changes to your files.

```
:copen
:%s/foo/bar/cg
:write
```

Answer (score 4):

#### External grep

*(uses grepprg, grepformat like in makeprg/errorformat; if grepprg=='internal' this is identical to internal grep)*

```
:grep fopen *.c
:copen
:cnext
```

#### Internal grep

```
:vimgrep /\<myVimregexp\>/ **/*.c
:copen
:cnext
```

etc.

#### Location list internal grep

```
:lvimgrep /\<myVimregexp\>/ **/*.c
:lopen
:lnext
```

etc.

### Bonus: doing external grep for the loaded buffers:

```
:silent bufdo grepadd fstream %
:copen
:cnext
```

etc.

#### External for all arguments:

```
:silent argdo grepadd fstream %
:copen
:cnext
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to point out with those examples. I know how to use grep and vimgrep. I don't see how this answer fits the question.

Comment: (a) Showing you a few ways to reduce the scope of grep in vim (b) showing you how to do such things for external grep. I'm sorry if it is a bit boring, but it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a patch to add the cdo (Quickfix do) command to vim, but it has not been pulled yet (as of 2015-03-25):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/dfyt-G6SMec

You may want to patch vim yourself to get this patch:

```
brew install hg # install mercurial, e.g. with homebrew
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim
# copy/download patch to . folder
patch -b -p1 < cdo.diff
./configure
make && make install
```