# How do I execute the same command on all lines contained in a error file of Vim?

Tags: vim

Scenario: I've run a static code analysis tool on my sources which found an issue on lots of my files.

The issue is that the statement

```
*retval = -1;
```

needs to be replaced by

```
if(retval != NULL)
{
    *retval = -1;
}
```

I already managed to have all relevant places in an [errorfile](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27errorfile%27) and started with the cycle

- [`:cn`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3acn)
- fix the code
- [`:cn`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3acn)

This workflow does it but I've got 400 places to touch, so it's a bit boring.

Could I instruct Vim (similar like for example [`bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3abufdo)) to correct the statement on all the places that are present in the errorfile?

And no, simply opening all the files and [`bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3abufdo) then is not an option since the construct `*retval = -1;` occurs several times but only needs to be fixed on the lines contained in the errorfile.

Comment: The question & answer here is very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686206

Comment: There's even [a patch pending](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/dfyt-G6SMec/_6h8pDUpeZMJ) for `:cdo` in core Vim, so if you're feeling especially charitable you could add a vote for that there, too.

Comment: if static analysis tools are able to find these issues you should be able to automatically fix it via semantic patching. E.g. coccinelle has a couple of example patches to fix `NULL` dereferences: [link](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/rules/#null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a macro:

1. Go to the first error
2. Press `qq` to record a macro the the `q` register
3. Fix that error
4. Save the buffer
5. Execute `:cn` to go to the next error
6. Press `q` to finish recording the macro

Now, you can type `100@q` - this will execute steps 3-5 100 times. But it won't be 100 times - at some point it will reach the end of the error list and fail. By then, all the errors will be fixed(for now...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro. Just type `qq` then do your `:cn` and fix the code, save, and then type `q1000@q`.