# Efficient way to refactor a class/method/string within a directory using vim

Tags: vim, refactoring

So far, I have been manually refactoring code by using the find-and-replace operation

```
%s:/stringiwanttoreplace/newstring/g
```

in vim.

But this is a slow and laborious process if I have *stringiwanttoreplace* in many files inside a specific directory.

My current/typical slow and laborious process involves a grep:-

```
grep -rn "stringiwanttoreplace" .
```

in my terminal to reveal all the locations/filenames where *stringiwanttoreplace* are; and now that I know which files contain *stringiwanttoreplace*, I will open each file one-by-one to perform the find-and-replace operation in each file.

Is there a more efficient workflow (in vim) to get this done?

**CLARIFICATION:** I would prefer a vim-based solution instead of a bash script/one-liner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the full sequence of commands that I would use:

```
/stringiwanttoreplace
:vimgrep /<c-r>// **
:Qargs
:argdo %s//newstring/g
:argdo update
```

In the first line, we search for the target pattern. That populates the last search pattern register ([`:help quote/`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_)), which means that we won't have to type it out in full again.

The `:vimgrep` command searches the entire project for the specified pattern. Type `<c-r>/` as <kbd>ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> followed by <kbd>/</kbd> - this inserts the contents of the last search pattern register onto the command line. The first and last `/` symbols are delimiters for the search field. The trailing `**` tells Vim to look inside every file and directory below the current directory.

At this point, the quickfix list will be populated with search matches from all matching files. `:Qargs` is a custom command, which populates the argument list with all of the files listed in the quickfix list. Here's the implementation:

```
command! -nargs=0 -bar Qargs execute 'args ' . QuickfixFilenames()
function! QuickfixFilenames()
  " Building a hash ensures we get each buffer only once
  let buffer_numbers = {}
  for quickfix_item in getqflist()
    let buffer_numbers[quickfix_item['bufnr']] = bufname(quickfix_item['bufnr'])
  endfor
  return join(values(buffer_numbers))
endfunction
```

Add that to your `vimrc` file.

Having run `:Qargs`, our argument list should now contain all of the files that include our target string. So we can run the substitution command with `:argdo`, to execute the command in each file. We can leave the search field of the substitution command blank, and it will automatically use the most recent search pattern. If you want, you could include the `c` flag when you run the substitution command, then you'll be prompted for confirmation.

Finally, the `:argdo update` command saves each file that was changed.

As [@Peter Rincker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438329/peter-rincker) pointed out, you should ensure that Vim's ['hidden'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'hidden') option is enabled, otherwise it will raise an error when you try to switch to another buffer before writing any changes to the active buffer.

Also, note that the last 3 commands can be executed in a single command line, by separating them with a pipe character.

```
:Qargs | argdo %s//replacement/gc | update
```

The `:Qargs` command is pinched from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686206/search-replace-using-quickfix-list-in-vim/5686810#5686810) (by me), which in turn was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792561/how-to-do-search-replace-with-ack-in-vim/4793316#4793316) by [DrAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72791/dral). A very [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830839/how-to-open-multiple-files-in-vim-after-vimgrep/6888929#6888929) was posted by [@ib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254635/ib), which suggests to me that Vim should really implement something like `:quickfixdo` natively.

Comment: @nelstorm: You may want to mention using `set hidden` or doing `:argdo %s//newstring/g|update` as `:argdo` by default will not abandon files.

Comment: I prefer joining `Qargs` and `argdo` commands in one: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=command -bang Qargdo exe 'args '.QuickfixFilenames() | argdo<bang> <args>`.

Comment: Thanks @nelstrom. Tried this out and it works great! :-)
Now I have a new vim trick up my sleeves, thanks to you.
Much appreciated for the super detailed answer!

Comment: I've created a simple plugin to wrap the `:Qargs` command: https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-qargs

Answer (score 4):

You *can* call this from within Vim (`:!find ...`) but you don't need to:

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/stringiwanttoreplace/newstring/g'
```

Fine-tune the file selection with the dozens of parameters described in

```
man find
```

(e.g., replace only in HTML files: `-name \*.html`)

This solution will try to attempt the replacement in *all* files. You *can* filter that through grep before, but that is just doing twice the work for no gain.

By the way: `sed` uses almost the same syntax for regular expressions as Vim (stemming from the same history).

Comment: If I do this inside the vim buffer, can I some how have a stdout that shows me exactly which files have been modified?

Comment: I use it mostly in a clean Git working tree, followed by a `git status` or `git diff`. If that doesn't work for you, you could use, e.g., `sed -i.SOMESTRANGESTRING ...`. Then `sed` would create backups, which you could, again, simply find with `find -name \*.SOMESTRANGESTRING`.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do it in Vim you can follow the suggestions [here](http://www.ibrahim-ahmed.com/2008/01/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in.html).

Comment: Oh, yes. I always forget about `:args`. +1

Comment: I agree that `:argdo` is the way to go, but running `:args app/views/*/*` is a scattershot way of populating the arguments list. The list will likely contain files that do not contain the search match that you want to replace, hence the requirement to include the `e` flag when running the substitute command. [My technique](http://bit.ly/ocf8uy) uses `:vimgrep` to populate the quickfix list, then copies each file referenced in that list into the argument list. This guarantees that `:argdo %s//replacement/g` only runs on files that contain the target string.

Answer (score 2):

You could open all the files and type

```
:bufdo :s/stringiwanttoreplace/newstring/g
```

It performs the search/replace in all your buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `vim` to do this, you can use command line tools. Using `sed` in a loop on the list of files to do this for you automatically. Something like this:

```
for each in `grep -l "stringiwanttoreplace" *` ;
do
    cat $each | sed -e "s/stringiwanttoreplace/newstring/g" > $each
; done
```

Comment: I was hoping for a vim-based solution instead of a bash script.

Comment: Fair enough, but this is easier - you don't need to invoke vim and cycle through the files. It's a one-step operation.

Answer (score 1):

vim7 has recursive grep built-in

```
:vimgrep /pattern/[j][g] file file1 file2 ... fileN
```

the result will be shown in a quickfix-window (:help quickfix)

to do the search recursively use the `**`-wildcard like

`**/*.c` to search through the current folder and recursively through all subdirectories.